# possible to make it so that left-word and right-word include spaces?

Tags: motion

Is it possible to adjust the behavior of the commands `'left-word'` and `'right-word'` (which I have bound to `m-left` and `m-right`) so that when I invoke, say, `'right-word'` and the point jumps to the end of the next word, it also includes the `space` following it? But NOT any punctuation.

I want to do this because I use `m-left` and `m-right`, with the mark set, to highlight regions for deletion. With current behavior, when I set the mark, then do `m-right` to highlight a word or set of words then delete them, I am left with two spaces in a row.

(Theoretically `left-word` should then also be greedy and jump to to a position BEFORE a PRECEDING space, though I almost always select words moving forward, not backward.)

When I'm deleting just one word, I invoke `kill-word`, but when deleting multiple words, I prefer to first highlight them all and then delete them all at once.

Comment: The following is a link to a custom function that I have been using for quite some time -- it is similar to what many word processors offer in terms of left/right movement by word:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489

Comment: OK and which functions should I bind to `m-left` and `m-right`? And do I have to add the code `(modify-syntax-entry ?* "w")` somewhere? (I use org-mode.)

Comment: You would need all three (3) paragraphs of code in the question -- to be placed inside your user configuration file.  I like to use these key bindings:  `(define-key global-map [M-right] 'lawlist-forward-entity)` and `(define-key global-map [M-left] 'lawlist-backward-entity)`  And then restart Emacs.  I gave credit to the answer because it put me on the right path, but everything that is needed is within the three (3) paragraphs of code in the question itself -- i.e., you do *not* need to add the sample one line of code from the answer.

Comment: **If** you do not need to change how the existing word commands work, and you only need to have your own commands that do what you want, **then** write those commands and bind them to whatever keys you want, and leave the existing functions alone. Changing existing functions will change any existing Lisp code that invokes them. Maybe that is what you want/need; but maybe it is not. Just be aware of the difference.

Comment: I bound `lawlist-forward-entity` to both `m-right` and `m-s-right`, but the spacing effect doesn't seem to work when the mark is set.

Comment: @Drew, yes, thanks, I want to just bind the keys to the new functions.

Comment: I have programmed the two functions to react differently when the region is active -- that is my personal preference for blocking/copying -- feel free to modify the behavior in your own setup to suit your needs.

Comment: What would the function look like without the different behavior for active regions?